# ValueError when looping over very large continous string (Project Euler prob 8)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am quite new to programming/Python, so my code might not be the most efficient. This particular refers to Problem 8 of Project Euler. It reads:

**Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?**

I have found the answer with the code below, but the code gives me issues depending on how I define the 1000-digit number, referred to as `a`. 
When `a` is written on a single line it works fine, but when I implement it with triple quotes on several lines (seperated by an enter) it gives `ValueError`s in the second `for` loop when reaching the end of a 'line' of `a`.

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening and how to work around it? Thanks in advance!

To be more precise, the error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

See code below:

```
 a = """7316717653... etc"""

    product = 1
    save = 0
    list1 = []
    list2 = []

    for ab in range(0, len(a)-13):
        start = ab
        stop = ab+13
        check = a[start:stop]
        list1.append(check)

    for a in list1:
        for b in a:
            product = product*int(b)
        list2.append(product)
        if product > save:
            save = product
            print('This is currently the largest product: ', product)
            product = 1
        else:
            product = 1

    print(max(list2))
```

Comment: It seems like the mistake is in the missing code, that you chose not to add. Please put the whole code so that we can understand what you try to do.

Comment: The way you generate `list1` makes some line separators (`\n`) end up in `a`, therefore in `b`. You probably want to skip characters that are line separators, or ensure that they are not ending up in `list1`.

Comment: Hi @pistache. I have included the first `for` loop code now as well. I have tried the concatenation method in your answer below, which works like a charm. I am still unsure where the line separators are being added. Is that the loop or the method of declaring `a` on multiple lines of code using `"""1000-digit number"""`. I was not aware of that.
Now that I realise it, it is quite unfortunate that I call my 1000-digit number `a` and my `for` loop variable `a` as well...

Comment: Triple-quotes will preserve line separators indeed, it's why they exist, to allow to input multiline strings. Your variable naming is indeed unfortunate :) Good luck and happy coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ending up with newlines (line separators, written as '\n') in `list1`, which is normal if you write your variable as a multiline text string.

You can try defining `a` as text without any newline, using standard Python concatenation :

`a = (
   "123456789"
   "123456789"
   "123456789"
)`

This will not create a tuple (they need a trailing comma), `a` will actually be the string `123456789123456789123456789`, without any separating newlines, and `int(b)` will stop complaining.